# Offline audio recording on iOS with OpenAL

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, openal

I'm using openAL to play sound samples at specific intervals and I want to export this to file (be it caf or aac or whatever). How can I do this with OpenAL without having my samples played in real time through the speakers/headphones?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about exporting your musical score as a complete audio piece, there's nothing in OpenAL that will do such a thing.

The only way I can think of would be to use Audio Units for playback, and use it offline mode to dump to a file.